# I'm gonna give probability regularization classes

Tags: probability, education

There's this group of high-school level kids that failed probability and they want me to teach them so they can pass that subject, i agreed to be their teacher for this 2 weeks, however i'm not experienced and i'm kind of nervous. I'm not sure how to begin the class, i was thinking that i should make a little exam to know how are they actually doing, but i don't know if thats prudent. Also, should i give this regulatization class as a normal class? but faster?
Please any recommendations will be appreciated

Comment: I'm no teacher but I was a tutor before. In general, I ALWAYS gave them a test in the beginning to see where they were. The only reason this isn't done in normal classes is because those classes have prerequisites and they assume you have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two weeks isn’t much time, so the time has to be spent as productively as possible. I would give them a pre-test to determine where they are and then concentrate on the areas in which they need the most work. Unfortunately this may turn out to be everything, or it may turn out that there’s little consistency from one student to another.

If it’s everything, I’d concentrate on the fundamentals even if it means skimping on some topics: the goal is to get them to an acceptable minimum level, and you can’t realistically expect to do much more than that. If it varies greatly from student to student, you may want to split your times: spend part of it working with the whole group on fundamentals and things on which most of them are weak, and part of it having them work individually or in small groups on their own trouble spots while you wander from one to another offering assistance and direction.